# Integrating $1/z$ over unit circle

Tags: integration, complex-analysis

I am having trouble with this (This is copied from Howie Complex Analysis):

> **Theorem:** Let $\gamma(t)=e^{it}\,(0\leq t\leq 2\pi)$. Then $\int_{\gamma} z^ndz=2\pi i$ if $n=-1$.
>
> **Proof**: $$\int_{\gamma}z^n\,dz=\int_0^{2\pi}r^ne^{nit}ie^{it}dt=i\int_0^{2\pi}r^ne^{(n+1)it}dt.$$ If $n=-1$ this becomes $i\int_0^{2\pi}dt=2\pi i$.

I wonder why not $i\int_0^{2\pi}r^{-1}dt=2\pi i/r$ in last line.

Comment: If you're integrating over the unit circle, then $r=1$

Comment: @learner Wouldn't it be more appropriate to post that as an answer (rather than a comment)? I mean, it's right and all, MSE just generally doesn't like answers being left in the comments. EDIT: Well I guess someone already kind of touched on it.

Comment: In the unit circle $r=1$

Comment: @EeveeTrainer: I think it's more suited as a comment since I'm not explaining anything. I'm just pointing out the obvious. It wouldn't seem fair to earn upvotes by posting that as an answer. Then again, that's just my opinion.

Comment: Fair enough, I getcha.

Comment: A better question: why the answer does **not** depends of $r$?

Answer (score 4):

In $\int_{\gamma} z^ndz$ we have $\gamma(t)=e^{it}$, hence $r=1$.

Answer (score 1):

In the unit circle $r=1$ , you're both right

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer Certainly it answers the question! The book says  $2\pi  i$, the question is why isn't it $2\pi i/r$ - pointing out that $r=1$ answers that perfectly.

Comment: My mistake. Deleted the comment

Answer (score 1):

$r=1$ because it is the unit circle with unit radius.

An alternative way to see there is no $r$ in the denominator of the answer is to apply the  [Residue Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem).

This tells you the value of the integral is $2\pi i \,\Sigma {\text{ residues}} $. The relevant residues of the function being integrated must be determined.

$1/z$ has a singularity at the origin with residue of $1$, so the answer is $2 \pi i$.